Bibliography grouped by author
I'm trying to achieve the following bibliography format (found in an old book):

It looks similar to biblatex with style = numeric. However, the entries are grouped by author. Is there a simple way to get that format? Maybe it is possible to tweak some existing style?
Citations in the text appear as "Cranston [3]" and "Cranston, Fabes, and Zhao [1]".

Two questions: (1) If an item has multiple authors, where is it put? Under the first one, under each one? And how do you mention the other authors? (2) Do you also want to reference/cite items, and how? In this style, multiple items will have the same number.

I have to disclaim that the following response doesn’t fully meet your needs: I couldn’t manage to reset the numbering of the items in the bibliography for each different author.
Generally, here are some pointers: the style you’re asking for (which isn’t as rare as one might think) is very similar to Ivan Valbusa’s biblatex-philosophy: his work provides three citation styles and the third one indeed is called “modern” and closely resembles your style. The difference is that you’re based on a numeric citation style, whereas Valbusa uses an authoryear style.
That’s why I suggest you have a look at the biblatex-philosophy documentation and the numeric style source. I based the following lines on the verbose style, as it seems to me to fit better.
At any rate, the following lines are a direct copy of parts of philosophy-modern and parts of numeric.
First of all, the simplest things: I suggest you load indeed the verbose style, enable labelnumber and provide only the initial for given names with giveninits=true, as suggested in your screenshot.
\usepackage[style=verbose,labelnumber,giveninits=true]{biblatex}

The following lines, taken from the numeric style (and as you’ll often see, I’ve shamelessly copied them), are used to format the labelnumber field, which will be used in the list of bibliographic references.
\DeclareFieldFormat{labelnumberwidth}{\mkbibbrackets{#1}}
\newbibmacro{bbx:labelnumber}{%
    \hspace{\hbibhang}%
    \printtext[labelnumberwidth]{%
        \printfield{labelprefix}%
        \printfield{labelnumber}}%
    \nopunct}
\setlength{\bibnamesep}{2\itemsep}

Note how I’ve doubled the length of \bibnamesep: this is to separate the bibliographic entries when the author’s name changes. And yes, en passant, you’ll need to make sure you define the sorting criterion based on the author’s name. Here are some further definitions of lengths, to align the indentations.
\setlength{\bibhang}{\ifnumequal{\parindent}{0}%
                        {2em}%
                        {2\parindent}}
\newlength{\hbibhang}
\setlength{\hbibhang}{\ifnumequal{\parindent}{0}%
                        {1em}%
                        {\parindent}}

I shamelessly copied the \postsep command from Ivan Valbusa. It’s used to insert a line break after the author's name, thus highlighting it according to your bibliographic style and, obviously, in line with Valbusa’s philosophy-modern one.
\newlength{\postnamesep}
\newcommand{\postsep}{%
    \null\par\nobreak\vskip\postnamesep%
    \hskip-\bibhang\ignorespaces}

I won’t comment too much on the redefinition of the author and editor bibmacros, precisely to input the line break and the labelnumber field after the author’s name of a specific bibliographic item. Please check the codes and documentation of the biblatex package and its standard styles and the biblatex-philosophy bundle by Valbusa. Just a disclaimer: I invite anyone with more knowledge than me to correct in case I’ve forgotten anything.
\renewbibmacro*{author}{%
    \ifboolexpr{test \ifuseauthor%
                and
                not test {\ifnameundef{author}}}%
        {\usebibmacro{bbx:dashcheck}%
            {\usebibmacro{bbx:labelnumber}}%
            {\usebibmacro{bbx:savehash}%
                \printnames[default]{author}%
                \postsep%
                \usebibmacro{bbx:labelnumber}%
                \iffieldundef{nameaddon}%
                    {}%
                    {\setunit{\addspace}%
                        \printfield{nameaddon}}%
                \iffieldundef{authortype}%
                    {\newunit}%
                    {\setunit{\printdelim{editorstrgdelim}}}}%
                \iffieldundef{authortype}%
                    {}%
                    {\usebibmacro{authorstrg}}}%
        {\global\undef\bbx@lasthash%
            \usebibmacro{labeltitle}%
            \setunit*{\printdelim{\addspace}}}}%

\renewbibmacro*{bbx:editor}[1]{%
    \ifboolexpr{test \ifuseeditor%
                and
                not test {\ifnameundef{editor}}}%
        {\usebibmacro{bbx:dashcheck}%
            {\usebibmacro{bbx:labelnumber}%
                \iffieldundef{editortype}%
                    {\newunit}%
                    {\setunit{\printdelim{editorstrgdelim}}}%
                \printtext[parens]{%
                \bibsentence\usebibmacro{#1}}%
                \clearname{editor}\nopunct}%
            {\usebibmacro{bbx:savehash}%
                \printnames[default]{editor}%
                \postsep%
                \usebibmacro{bbx:labelnumber}%
                \iffieldundef{nameaddon}%
                    {}%
                    {\setunit{\addspace}%
                        \printfield{nameaddon}}%
                \iffieldundef{editortype}%
                    {\newunit}%
                    {\setunit{\printdelim{editorstrgdelim}}}%
                \printtext[parens]{%
                \bibsentence\usebibmacro{#1}}%
                \clearname{editor}\nopunct}}%
        {\global\undef\bbx@lasthash%
            \usebibmacro{labeltitle}%
            \setunit*{\printdelim{\addspace}}}}%

Here, instead, is the redefinition of the bibmacros that work in the citation commands and of the citation commands themselves. I had to copy the codes entirely from the numeric style.
\providebool{bbx:subentry}
\newbool{cbx:parens}
\DeclareFieldFormat{bibhyperref}{\bibhyperref{#1}}
\renewbibmacro*{cite}{%
    \printtext[bibhyperref]{%
        \printfield{labelprefix}%
        \printfield{labelnumber}%
        \ifbool{bbx:subentry}%
            {\printfield{entrysetcount}}%
            {}}}

\renewbibmacro*{textcite}{%
    \iffieldequals{namehash}{\cbx@lasthash}%
        {\setunit{\multicitedelim}}%
        {\ifnameundef{labelname}%
            {\printfield[citetitle]{labeltitle}}%
            {\printnames{labelname}}%
            \setunit*{\printdelim{namelabeldelim}}%
            \printtext{\bibopenbracket}\global\booltrue{cbx:parens}%
            \stepcounter{textcitecount}%
            \savefield{namehash}{\cbx@lasthash}}%
    \ifnumequal{\value{citecount}}{1}%
        {\usebibmacro{prenote}}%
        {}%
    \usebibmacro{cite}%
    \setunit{\ifbool{cbx:parens}%
        {\bibclosebracket\global\boolfalse{cbx:parens}}%
        {}%
    \textcitedelim}}

\renewbibmacro*{textcite:init}{%
    \ifnumless{\value{multicitecount}}{2}%
        {\global\boolfalse{cbx:parens}%
            \global\undef\cbx@lasthash}%
        {\global\undef\cbx@lasthash}}

\newbibmacro*{textcite:postnote}{%
    \usebibmacro{postnote}%
    \ifthenelse{\value{multicitecount}=\value{multicitetotal}}%
        {\setunit{}%
            \printtext{\ifbool{cbx:parens}%
                {\bibclosebracket\global\boolfalse{cbx:parens}}%
                {}}}%
        {\setunit{\ifbool{cbx:parens}%
                {\bibclosebracket\global\boolfalse{cbx:parens}}%
                {}%
                \textcitedelim}}}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\cbx@textcite}
    {\usebibmacro{textcite:init}}%
    {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
        \usebibmacro{textcite}}%
    {}%
    {\usebibmacro{textcite:postnote}}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\textcite}[\cbx@textcite@init\cbx@textcite]
    {\gdef\cbx@savedkeys{}%
        \citetrackerfalse%
        \pagetrackerfalse%
        \DeferNextCitekeyHook%
        \usebibmacro{textcite:init}}%
    {\ifthenelse{\iffirstcitekey\AND\value{multicitetotal}>0}
        {\protected@xappto\cbx@savedcites{()(\thefield{multipostnote})}%
            \global\clearfield{multipostnote}}%
        {}%
        \xappto\cbx@savedkeys{\thefield{entrykey},}%
        \iffieldequals{namehash}{\cbx@lasthash}%
            {}%
            {\stepcounter{textcitetotal}%
                \savefield{namehash}{\cbx@lasthash}}}%
    {}%
    {\protected@xappto\cbx@savedcites{%
        [\thefield{prenote}][\thefield{postnote}]{\cbx@savedkeys}}}

\DeclareDelimcontextAlias{cbx@textcite}{textcite}

\renewrobustcmd{\cbx@textcite@init}[2]{%
    \setcounter{textcitetotal}{0}%
    \setcounter{textcitecount}{0}%
    \def\cbx@savedcites{#1}#2%
    \ifnumgreater{\value{textcitetotal}}{0}%
        {\cbx@savedcites}%
        {}}

\DeclareMultiCiteCommand{\cbx@textcites}{\cbx@textcite}{}
\DeclareMultiCiteCommand{\textcites}[\cbx@textcites@init\cbx@textcites]{\textcite}{}

\let\cbx@textcites@init\cbx@textcite@init
\pretocmd{\cbx@textcites@init}{\UseNextMultiCiteHook}{}{}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\cite}[\mkbibbrackets]
    {\usebibmacro{prenote}}%
    {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
        \usebibmacro{cite}}%
    {\multicitedelim}%
    {\usebibmacro{postnote}}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\parencite}[\mkbibbrackets]
    {\usebibmacro{prenote}}%
    {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
        \usebibmacro{cite}}%
    {\multicitedelim}%
    {\usebibmacro{postnote}}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\footcite}[\mkbibfootnote]
    {\usebibmacro{prenote}}%
    {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
        \usebibmacro{cite}}%
    {\multicitedelim}%
    {\usebibmacro{postnote}}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\footcitetext}[\mkbibfootnotetext]
    {\usebibmacro{prenote}}%
    {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
        \usebibmacro{cite}}%
    {\multicitedelim}%
    {\usebibmacro{postnote}}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\smartcite}[\iffootnote\mkbibbrackets\mkbibfootnote]
    {\usebibmacro{prenote}}%
    {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
        \usebibmacro{cite}}%
    {\multicitedelim}%
    {\usebibmacro{postnote}}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\supercite}[\mkbibsuperscript]
    {\iffieldundef{prenote}%
        {}%
        {\BibliographyWarning{Ignoring prenote argument}}%
        \iffieldundef{postnote}%
            {}%
            {\BibliographyWarning{Ignoring postnote argument}}}%
    {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
        \usebibmacro{cite}}%
    {\supercitedelim}%
    {}

Remind that the last two input excerpts (the latter and then the second to last, which redefines the author and editor bibmacros) must be placed between the \makeatletter and \makeatother commands.
Before I close and give you an MWEB, a note, almost to apologise for the fact that this answer doesn’t fully satisfy your question. As I said at the beginning, I am not able to «reset» the numbering of the bibliographic list items depending on the author’s name. However, if you like to see the glass half full, this allows you to make only numerical citations: that’s why, by redefining the citation commands, I copied from numeric: this allows you to use \textcite, if you want to call the author and the reference number (and \citeauthor, if you want only the author), while \cite, if you want only the number.
Alright, now I’m really going to end this very long answer. Here you are a MWEB, so you can verify my suggestions.
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[style=verbose,labelnumber,giveninits=true]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\DeclareFieldFormat{labelnumberwidth}{\mkbibbrackets{#1}}
\newbibmacro{bbx:labelnumber}{%
    \hspace{\hbibhang}%
    \printtext[labelnumberwidth]{%
        \printfield{labelprefix}%
        \printfield{labelnumber}}%
    \nopunct}
\setlength{\bibnamesep}{2\itemsep}

\setlength{\bibhang}{\ifnumequal{\parindent}{0}%
                        {2em}%
                        {2\parindent}}
\newlength{\hbibhang}
\setlength{\hbibhang}{\ifnumequal{\parindent}{0}%
                        {1em}%
                        {\parindent}}

\newlength{\postnamesep}
\newcommand{\postsep}{%
    \null\par\nobreak\vskip\postnamesep%
    \hskip-\bibhang\ignorespaces}

\makeatletter
\renewbibmacro*{author}{%
    \ifboolexpr{test \ifuseauthor%
                and
                not test {\ifnameundef{author}}}%
        {\usebibmacro{bbx:dashcheck}%
            {\usebibmacro{bbx:labelnumber}}%
            {\usebibmacro{bbx:savehash}%
                \printnames[default]{author}%
                \postsep%
                \usebibmacro{bbx:labelnumber}%
                \iffieldundef{nameaddon}%
                    {}%
                    {\setunit{\addspace}%
                        \printfield{nameaddon}}%
                \iffieldundef{authortype}%
                    {\newunit}%
                    {\setunit{\printdelim{editorstrgdelim}}}}%
                \iffieldundef{authortype}%
                    {}%
                    {\usebibmacro{authorstrg}}}%
        {\global\undef\bbx@lasthash%
            \usebibmacro{labeltitle}%
            \setunit*{\printdelim{\addspace}}}}%

\renewbibmacro*{bbx:editor}[1]{%
    \ifboolexpr{test \ifuseeditor%
                and
                not test {\ifnameundef{editor}}}%
        {\usebibmacro{bbx:dashcheck}%
            {\usebibmacro{bbx:labelnumber}%
                \iffieldundef{editortype}%
                    {\newunit}%
                    {\setunit{\printdelim{editorstrgdelim}}}%
                \printtext[parens]{%
                \bibsentence\usebibmacro{#1}}%
                \clearname{editor}\nopunct}%
            {\usebibmacro{bbx:savehash}%
                \printnames[default]{editor}%
                \postsep%
                \usebibmacro{bbx:labelnumber}%
                \iffieldundef{nameaddon}%
                    {}%
                    {\setunit{\addspace}%
                        \printfield{nameaddon}}%
                \iffieldundef{editortype}%
                    {\newunit}%
                    {\setunit{\printdelim{editorstrgdelim}}}%
                \printtext[parens]{%
                \bibsentence\usebibmacro{#1}}%
                \clearname{editor}\nopunct}}%
        {\global\undef\bbx@lasthash%
            \usebibmacro{labeltitle}%
            \setunit*{\printdelim{\addspace}}}}%

\providebool{bbx:subentry}
\newbool{cbx:parens}
\DeclareFieldFormat{bibhyperref}{\bibhyperref{#1}}
\renewbibmacro*{cite}{%
    \printtext[bibhyperref]{%
        \printfield{labelprefix}%
        \printfield{labelnumber}%
        \ifbool{bbx:subentry}%
            {\printfield{entrysetcount}}%
            {}}}

\renewbibmacro*{textcite}{%
    \iffieldequals{namehash}{\cbx@lasthash}%
        {\setunit{\multicitedelim}}%
        {\ifnameundef{labelname}%
            {\printfield[citetitle]{labeltitle}}%
            {\printnames{labelname}}%
            \setunit*{\printdelim{namelabeldelim}}%
            \printtext{\bibopenbracket}\global\booltrue{cbx:parens}%
            \stepcounter{textcitecount}%
            \savefield{namehash}{\cbx@lasthash}}%
    \ifnumequal{\value{citecount}}{1}%
        {\usebibmacro{prenote}}%
        {}%
    \usebibmacro{cite}%
    \setunit{\ifbool{cbx:parens}%
        {\bibclosebracket\global\boolfalse{cbx:parens}}%
        {}%
    \textcitedelim}}

\renewbibmacro*{textcite:init}{%
    \ifnumless{\value{multicitecount}}{2}%
        {\global\boolfalse{cbx:parens}%
            \global\undef\cbx@lasthash}%
        {\global\undef\cbx@lasthash}}

\newbibmacro*{textcite:postnote}{%
    \usebibmacro{postnote}%
    \ifthenelse{\value{multicitecount}=\value{multicitetotal}}%
        {\setunit{}%
            \printtext{\ifbool{cbx:parens}%
                {\bibclosebracket\global\boolfalse{cbx:parens}}%
                {}}}%
        {\setunit{\ifbool{cbx:parens}%
                {\bibclosebracket\global\boolfalse{cbx:parens}}%
                {}%
                \textcitedelim}}}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\cbx@textcite}
    {\usebibmacro{textcite:init}}%
    {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
        \usebibmacro{textcite}}%
    {}%
    {\usebibmacro{textcite:postnote}}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\textcite}[\cbx@textcite@init\cbx@textcite]
    {\gdef\cbx@savedkeys{}%
        \citetrackerfalse%
        \pagetrackerfalse%
        \DeferNextCitekeyHook%
        \usebibmacro{textcite:init}}%
    {\ifthenelse{\iffirstcitekey\AND\value{multicitetotal}>0}
        {\protected@xappto\cbx@savedcites{()(\thefield{multipostnote})}%
            \global\clearfield{multipostnote}}%
        {}%
        \xappto\cbx@savedkeys{\thefield{entrykey},}%
        \iffieldequals{namehash}{\cbx@lasthash}%
            {}%
            {\stepcounter{textcitetotal}%
                \savefield{namehash}{\cbx@lasthash}}}%
    {}%
    {\protected@xappto\cbx@savedcites{%
        [\thefield{prenote}][\thefield{postnote}]{\cbx@savedkeys}}}

\DeclareDelimcontextAlias{cbx@textcite}{textcite}

\renewrobustcmd{\cbx@textcite@init}[2]{%
    \setcounter{textcitetotal}{0}%
    \setcounter{textcitecount}{0}%
    \def\cbx@savedcites{#1}#2%
    \ifnumgreater{\value{textcitetotal}}{0}%
        {\cbx@savedcites}%
        {}}

\DeclareMultiCiteCommand{\cbx@textcites}{\cbx@textcite}{}
\DeclareMultiCiteCommand{\textcites}[\cbx@textcites@init\cbx@textcites]{\textcite}{}

\let\cbx@textcites@init\cbx@textcite@init
\pretocmd{\cbx@textcites@init}{\UseNextMultiCiteHook}{}{}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\cite}[\mkbibbrackets]
    {\usebibmacro{prenote}}%
    {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
        \usebibmacro{cite}}%
    {\multicitedelim}%
    {\usebibmacro{postnote}}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\parencite}[\mkbibbrackets]
    {\usebibmacro{prenote}}%
    {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
        \usebibmacro{cite}}%
    {\multicitedelim}%
    {\usebibmacro{postnote}}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\footcite}[\mkbibfootnote]
    {\usebibmacro{prenote}}%
    {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
        \usebibmacro{cite}}%
    {\multicitedelim}%
    {\usebibmacro{postnote}}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\footcitetext}[\mkbibfootnotetext]
    {\usebibmacro{prenote}}%
    {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
        \usebibmacro{cite}}%
    {\multicitedelim}%
    {\usebibmacro{postnote}}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\smartcite}[\iffootnote\mkbibbrackets\mkbibfootnote]
    {\usebibmacro{prenote}}%
    {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
        \usebibmacro{cite}}%
    {\multicitedelim}%
    {\usebibmacro{postnote}}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\supercite}[\mkbibsuperscript]
    {\iffieldundef{prenote}%
        {}%
        {\BibliographyWarning{Ignoring prenote argument}}%
        \iffieldundef{postnote}%
            {}%
            {\BibliographyWarning{Ignoring postnote argument}}}%
    {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
        \usebibmacro{cite}}%
    {\supercitedelim}%
    {}
\makeatother

\title{A style for user876301}
\author{Francesco Contini}
\date{10th December 2024}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section{Introduction}

\begin{itemize}
    \item \cite{westfahl:space,angenendt};
    \item \textcite{westfahl:space,angenendt};
    \item \textcite{aristotle:anima,aristotle:physics};
    \item \citeauthor{aristotle:poetics};
    \item \cite{gaonkar};
    \item \textcite{gaonkar:in};
    \item \cite{westfahl:frontier}.
\end{itemize}

\printbibliography

\end{document}


You might want to have a look at Get the bibliography style of Kelley's book General topology using bibtex, though you could also build upon the ext-authornumber style without too much effort nowadays.
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[backend=biber, style=ext-authornumber]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\setlength{\bibnamesep}{\baselineskip}
\setlength{\bibhang}{3em}
\DeclareDelimFormat[bib]{namenumberdelim}{\endgraf\hspace{-\bibhang}}
\renewcommand*{\bibnamedash}{}
\DeclareFieldFormat{bibextraname}{\makebox[\leftmargin][l]{\mkbibbrackets{#1}}}
\DeclareDelimFormat[bib]{nametitledelim}{}

\begin{document}
Lorem \autocite{sigfridsson}
ipsum \autocite{knuth:ct:b,knuth:ct:a,knuth:ct:c}
dolor \autocite{worman}
sit \autocite{geer}

\printbibliography
\end{document}


